# How do you upload images to content other than articles

Tags: media

How do you upload images to content other than articles? I tried adding  into the body of a block where I want a photo but it doesn't work. I've forgotten a lot of my html.

---

I'm doing something wrong. LEt's say, I want some sidebar blocks or even trtyptich blocks with an image in it. Do I start w/creating a view, a block, or an image that links to an article with the image and a caption showing in that block? That would help me immensely.

Comment: Hello, and welcome on Drupal Answers. You are actually asking two questions: how to upload an image for a node whose content type is not Article, and how to show the uploaded image in a block. It is better to keep a question for each asked questions.

Answer (score 1):

Enter images into your content fields. On Add content type, go to "Manage fields," and under "Field type" select "Image." This will allow you to upload an image into that content type. If you want to add a referent to the image with `<img src="image URL">`, I suggest you switching from filtered HTML to full HTML as input format of the node body.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I think I tried that, but will try it again. I think I do switch everything to full html in case I need it. Tx! : )